# Escape `@` in yesod templates

Tags: haskell, escaping, template-engine, yesod

I'm trying to use `@font-face` selector in cassius template with no luck.

Cassius uses `@` for interpolation, is there any way to escape it?

I've tried `@@` and `\@`, none of them works.

Following template

```
@font-face
      font-family: 'Monsieur La Doulaise'
      src: url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise')
```

Results in

```
src: url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monsieur+La+Doulaise');}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty ugly, but may work:

`...
defaultLayout $ do
    let atSym = "@"
    [cassius|#{atSym}font-face ... |]
...`

in other words, bind a string to the value of "@" and interpolate that in the cassius file.  I can't check the syntax now but it may work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to your question but I thought I will let you know that ran into something related this morning. I had the following CSS section:

```
.myclass {
   background: #d880efe;
   background-image:url(@{StaticR img_myimage_png});
   /* more stuff */
 }
```

When Yesod compiled the CSS file, it did not generate the URL for the `background-image`. In fact, it skipped over the entire line and created a slightly different `background` property. I ended up skipping the `@{StaticR ...} and hard-coded the URL. When I get a chance I will create a reproducible code.

So I am guessing this is an issue with `@` interpolation and not so much escaping. Do you mind trying a `@{Handler}` for your `src`? If that line is not getting generated then it may be a different issue that we need to file a bug report for.

Comment: Hi. I don't think our questions are related. I just need an `@` symbol to appear in resulting output. I've tried your code and it works just fine. Maybe you should try `cabal clean`, it helps when strange things happen.